# EdgeInsetsDirectional.symmetric vs EdgeInsets.symmetric?

Tags: flutter

Can anyone explain?
When should use which one?
Specialy, I need to use paddings for lingual text and some languages are rtl.

Comment: I would think if you're dealing with rtl texts I would use `EdgeInsetsDirectional` wherever you can. But in the `symmetric` use case it doesn't really matter. But I would still stick to `EdgeInsetsDirectional` just in case you want to edit it at some point to a non-symmetric one

Answer (score 2):

The `EdgeInsetsDirectional` and `EdgeInsets` are same for symmetric. source [Official Flutter Documentation](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/9cd3d0d9ff05768afa249e036acc66e8abe93bff/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/edge_insets.dart#L685).

It will only differ if you specify different values for either start/left or end/right.

`left` insert it in left side of the text where `start` at beginning of the text (It would right in rtl language),

`right` insert it in right side of the text where `end` at the end of the text (means It would left in rtl language)

Answer (score 1):

`EdgeInsets.symmetric` is used to define symmetric padding around all 4 sides of a widget. It takes a single value for the vertical and horizontal padding.

On the other hand, `EdgeInsetsDirectional.symmetric` is also used to define symmetric padding around all 4 sides but it takes separate values for the ***start/end*** and ***top/bottom*** directions. This is useful when dealing with text or widgets in **right-to-left** or somehow **bottom-to-top** layout.

Example reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bq37eFbRMc0